# How can I read a SAS format datafile in Vaex without converting it to a pandas data frame first?

Tags: python, sas, bigdata, vaex

I was trying to load a 30GB SAS format data file in pandas, but the memory does not allow me to do so. I then find a python library called Vaex, which suppose to analyze big datasets with no memory wasted. However, Vaex can only read data from certain file formats, such as CSV or HDF5. The method provided by its website below suggests converting the sas to pandas before it's been converted to vaex. It then back to my previous problems that I cannot even open this big data file using pandas. Thanks in Advance!!!!

pandas_df = pd.read_sas('./data/io/sample_airline.sas7bdat')

df = vaex.from_pandas(pandas_df, copy_index=False)

df

Comment: Perhaps try to read the sas file in chunks, and write to a HDF5 in chunks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612304/reading-huge-sas-dataset-in-python