# Python pyreadstat name 'row' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm adapting this code from this thread:
[Reading huge sas dataset in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612304/reading-huge-sas-dataset-in-python)

When I test run with my own dataset :

```
filename = 'df_53.SAS7BDAT'
CHUNKSIZE = 50000
offset = 0
# Get the function object in a variable getChunk
if filename.lower().endswith('sas7bdat'):
    getChunk = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat
else:
    getChunk = pyreadstat.read_xport
allChunk,_ = getChunk(row['/data/research1/test/cc/53/'], row_limit=CHUNKSIZE, row_offset=offset)
allChunk = allChunk.astype('category')

while True:
    offset += CHUNKSIZE
    # for xpt data, use pyreadstat.read_xpt()
    chunk, _ = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat(filename, row_limit=CHUNKSIZE, row_offset=offset)
    if chunk.empty: break  # if chunk is empty, it means the entire data has been read, so break

    for eachCol in chunk:  #converting each column to categorical 
        colUnion = pd.api.types.union_categoricals([allChunk[eachCol], chunk[eachCol]])
        allChunk[eachCol] = pd.Categorical(allChunk[eachCol], categories=colUnion.categories)
        chunk[eachCol] = pd.Categorical(chunk[eachCol], categories=colUnion.categories)

    allChunk = pd.concat([allChunk, chunk])  #Append each chunk to the resulting dataframe
```

I received an error that says:

`name 'row' is not defined`

Anyone has any idea how to fix the error?

Comment: What were you expecting `row['/data/research1/test/cc/53/']` to do?  You probably just want to pass the filename for that parameter.

Comment: on the original post, it says `getChunk(row['filePath']` , filepath is a directory right?

Comment: I tried with the absolute path `/data/research1/test/cc/53/df_53.sas7bdat`, got this error : `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`